# Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I deliberately erase totally windows os also efi partition from my laptop to create ubuntu as a default os but after that
error like this is showing

```
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
```

Please tell me way to solve this

I am using Dell Inspiron 3593

Comment: Why wouldn't Ubuntu detect other OSes?  You've provided no OS/release details; but Ubuntu carries patches so what you appear to be asking about does **not** apply to most Ubuntu products, what OS/release are you actually asking about?  (I'm involved with QA & except for a few weeks during the *alpha* cycle of one release; Ubuntu has always detected other partitions & OSes on other drives for all releases up to current *mantic*)

Comment: @guiverc From Grub manual:`‘GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER’

    The grub-mkconfig has a feature to use the external os-prober program to discover other operating systems installed on the same machine and generate appropriate menu entries for them. It is disabled by default since automatic and silent execution of os-prober, and creating boot entries based on that data, is a potential attack vector. Set this option to ‘false’ to enable this feature in the grub-mkconfig command.`

Comment: @mook765 I'm aware of the feature, the change was reported (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html) and tracked for *jammy* or 22.04, until the patches were applied (*whilst still in alpha*) and the issue shouldn't exist on any *supported* media which is why I asked for OS/release details..   The box I'm using now (*not Ubuntu, but Debian*) doesn't detect the Ubuntu on this install due to that issue, however my QA-test installs of Ubuntu (*jammy*, *lunar*, *mantic*) all detect other Ubuntu & Debian install for example. My understanding..

Comment: Sir, Could you share with me command line in details , actually I am new  user of Linux os

Comment: I performed a re-install of Ubuntu *jammy* (using the *daily*; I do it ~weekly on this box instead of performing updates...) only yesterday, and on reboot confirmed it detected my other Ubuntu installs (*there are numerous*) & the Debian I'm currently using (*I use this box maybe two hours nightly; it's not my primary PC*) and I needed to do nothing post install for all OSes to be offered to me at grub...  (*outside of my usual change which has Debian the default on this box, but that's my preference given I do my own stuff on Debian on this thing, with Ubuntu's not having my private keys*)

Comment: Os-prober also looks in ESP - efi system partition. So if you deleted ESP, did you also delete other installs boot files? But if Ubuntu or flavors you only get one "ubuntu" entry in UEFI & grub then boots all other "ubuntu" entries.

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your question so that the part which quotes the warning message you get is recognizable as such. Depending on whether you want `os-prober` to work, or just the message to go away, pick one of the answers below, and add a comment there if you need additional clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Just do the following

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and uncomment `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` or add it if not exist then execute

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo os-prober
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
```

and then restart your labtop to see changes
if I helped you please upvote

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single system installed on that machine, you don't need `os-prober` at all.  If you remove the `os-prober` package, the warning will go away.