Grub: can't load Windows after migrating to SSD
I believe my problems are 2-fold (unless they aren't) but they come from my migrating some of my HDD partitions to a new SSD drive. Using Boot-Repair I can now start Ubuntu 22.04, but Window 10 won't start, and I'm pretty sure that Grub is part of it.
The two drives I have are /dev/sda and /dev/nvme0n1. I never used any of these drive-managing tools to write to /dev/sda, so nothing should have happened to it. But if I try to boot Windows from either, it won't work.
/dev/sda consists of:

/dev/sda1: Linux swap
/dev/sda2: Linux boot
/dev/sda3: another ext4
/dev/sda4: Windows 10

/dev/nvme0n1 consists of:

/dev/nvme0n1p1: clone of /dev/sda2 (Linux boot)
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clone of /dev/sda4 (Windows 10)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: No file system (yet) but it's marked ext4

I've run os-prober and grub-update from /dev/nvme0n1p1 so those tools have done all they can.
Booting from /dev/nvme0n1
Grub now can access every partition on either drive, and I can start Ubuntu, but if I try to boot /dev/nvme0n1p2 or /dev/sda4 I immediately get told "A disk read error occurred // Press Ctrl-Alt-Del to restart"
Boot Repair Summary:
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p1 into the MBR of nvme0n1.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1 (TEAM TM8FP6512G) disk!

The boot files of [nvme0n1p1 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the MacOS entry to your GRUB menu.

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p1 into the MBR of nvme0n1.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s



Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p1/etc/default/grub

==================== Reinstall the grub2 of /dev/nvme0n1p1 =====================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2

==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/nvme0n1p1 into the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1 grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-116-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-113-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-113-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-104-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-104-generic
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda2

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1 (TEAM TM8FP6512G) disk!

The boot files of [nvme0n1p1 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)Please set your BIOS in Legacy mode in order to start your Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, then type command [sudo update-grub] in order to add the MacOS entry to your GRUB menu.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos2)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       nvme0n1p1 and looks at sector 17096832 of the same 
                       hard drive for the stage2 file, but no stage2 files 
                       can be found at this location.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, nvme0n1p2 
                       starts at sector 1743808512. But according to the info 
                       from fdisk, nvme0n1p2 starts at sector 204802048.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub Legacy
    Boot sector info:  Grub Legacy (v) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda2 and looks at sector 17096832 of the same hard 
                       drive for the stage2 file, but no stage2 files can be 
                       found at this location.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 4 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on nvme0n1p1
OS#2:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on sda2
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p2
OS#4:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: P2.20(5.17) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 000D
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 000D,0000,000C,000E,000A
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(4,MBR,0x1d8e78d7,0x67f06800,0xc7ff800)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot000A* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........{.T.E.A.M. .T.M.8.F.P.6.5.1.2.G....................A..........................dy..... .....>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.T.P.B.F.2.3.1.2.1.2.0.0.3.0.2.0.2.9.9.2........BO..NO........u.S.T.3.1.0.0.0.5.2.4.A.S....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .V.9.C.P.E.W.2.N........BO
Boot000C* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........u.H.L.-.D.T.-.S.T. .D.V.D.R.A.M. .G.H.2.4.N.S.7.0....................A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.K.B.U.J.5.0.6.5.3. .9. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot000D* UEFI OS   HD(2,MBR,0x14eb2669,0x23c,0x2130)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)..BO
Boot000E* USB   BBS(USB,,0x0)..GO..NO........a.J.M.i.c.r.o.n. .T.e.c.h. .0.5.0.8....................A................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.6........BO

ed45adef8b51b968450611d9d89804b4   sda4/Boot/bootx64.efi
13bbe79f47b4d57f791e51f5c01f7ac8   sda4/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
ed45adef8b51b968450611d9d89804b4   sda4/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
0155f61ba8a2b8a43ff6c21012230205   sda4/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda4    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x000d06a8
         Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
nvme0n1p1           2048  204802047 204800000  97.7G 83 Linux
nvme0n1p2 *    204802048  598018047 393216000 187.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
nvme0n1p3      598018048 1000214527 402196480 191.8G 83 Linux
Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x1d8e78d7
     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1             2048   27097087   27095040  12.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
sda2         27097088  152436735  125339648  59.8G 83 Linux
sda3        152436736 1743808511 1591371776 758.8G 83 Linux
sda4  *    1743808512 1953521663  209713152   100G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x14eb2669
     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0    5138431    5138432   2.5G  0 Empty
sdb2           572       9067       8496   4.1M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       5140480 1953525167 1948384688 929.1G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST31000524AS:;
1:1049kB:13.9GB:13.9GB:linux-swap(v1)::;
2:13.9GB:78.0GB:64.2GB:ext4::;
3:78.0GB:893GB:815GB:ext4::;
4:893GB:1000GB:107GB:ntfs::boot;
sdb:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:JMicron Tech:;
2:293kB:4643kB:4350kB:::esp;
3:2632MB:1000GB:998GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:msdos:TEAM TM8FP6512G:;
1:1049kB:105GB:105GB:ext4::;
2:105GB:306GB:201GB:ntfs::boot;
3:306GB:512GB:206GB:ext4::;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdb: 4.43MiB:2510MiB:2506MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                   
├─sda1      swap     019e69d5-cbf4-4bf4-8f6f-1002f27bb8ad 1d8e78d7-01                                                 
├─sda2      ext4     f7c1939e-6939-417e-af42-7f9980294b87 1d8e78d7-02                                                 
├─sda3      ext4     e7dd6327-d1f8-40b8-9c74-5f1c9b088ebd 1d8e78d7-03                                                 
└─sda4      ntfs     08C80847C808358A                     1d8e78d7-04                                                 
sdb         iso9660  2023-12-23-05-05-55-00                                                    Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdb1      iso9660  2023-12-23-05-05-55-00               14eb2669-01                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdb2      vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            14eb2669-02                          ESP                    
└─sdb3      ext4     dbdf4531-251f-4191-a2c3-4e2904238123 14eb2669-03                          writable               
nvme0n1                                                                                                               
├─nvme0n1p1 ext4     da5f7597-a235-4b9e-a118-16f157daf97d 000d06a8-01                          UBUNTU_ROOT            
├─nvme0n1p2 ntfs     08C80847C808358A                     000d06a8-02                                                 
└─nvme0n1p3 ext4     87181479-e982-492f-9ba5-c36df1fe41bf 000d06a8-03                                                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                               55.1G  37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                               99.1G  47% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                179G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/sda2                                                      20G  61% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                                                     284G  62% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4                                                    11.3G  89% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sdb1                                                        0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                                              ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=32639
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda2                                                   ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=32639
/dev/sda3                                                   ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=32750
/dev/sda4                                                   fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1                                                   iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

=================== nvme0n1p1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   da5f7597-a235-4b9e-a118-16f157daf97d
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) (on sda2)   f7c1939e-6939-417e-af42-7f9980294b87
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p1/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=da5f7597-a235-4b9e-a118-16f157daf97d   /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=e7dd6327-d1f8-40b8-9c74-5f1c9b088ebd /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=019e69d5-cbf4-4bf4-8f6f-1002f27bb8ad none            swap    sw              0       0
192.168.1.105:/mnt/mainhdd/dospace/ /mnt/pi/    nfs defaults,noauto,wsize=65536,retrans=5   0   0

==================== nvme0n1p1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p1: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  61.751464844 = 66.305130496   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  38.652488708 = 41.502793728   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  40.816543579 = 43.826429952   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-113-generic                2
  38.652488708 = 41.502793728   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-116-generic                2
  31.168018341 = 33.466404864   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic                 1
   7.794952393 = 8.369766400    boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-104-generic                 1
  40.816543579 = 43.826429952   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
  59.860347748 = 64.274558976   boot/initrd.img                                5
  29.602535248 = 31.785480192   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-113-generic             8
  59.860347748 = 64.274558976   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-116-generic             5
  57.750972748 = 62.009634816   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic              8
  49.625972748 = 53.285482496   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-104-generic              4
  29.602535248 = 31.785480192   boot/initrd.img.old                            8

=================== nvme0n1p1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 21  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 11  2014 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   f7c1939e-6939-417e-af42-7f9980294b87
Windows 10 (on sda4)   08C80847C808358A
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f7c1939e-6939-417e-af42-7f9980294b87 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=e7dd6327-d1f8-40b8-9c74-5f1c9b088ebd /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=019e69d5-cbf4-4bf4-8f6f-1002f27bb8ad none            swap    sw              0       0
192.168.1.105:/mnt/mainhdd/dospace/ /mnt/pi/    nfs defaults,noauto,wsize=65536,retrans=5   0   0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  19.049831390 = 20.454600704   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  71.342910767 = 76.603867136   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  53.736465454 = 57.699090432   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  28.858394623 = 30.986465280   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-112-generic                2
  53.736465454 = 57.699090432   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-113-generic                2
  44.087940216 = 47.339065344   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-76-generic                 1
  20.714874268 = 22.242426880   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-104-generic                 1
  28.858394623 = 30.986465280   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
  70.022457123 = 75.186040832   boot/initrd.img                                3
  71.408851624 = 76.674670592   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic             5
  70.022457123 = 75.186040832   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-113-generic             3
  66.545894623 = 71.453110272   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic              4
  46.304576874 = 49.719160832   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-104-generic              5
  71.408851624 = 76.674670592   boot/initrd.img.old                            5

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 21  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 11  2014 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdb

sprunge.us ko ()

Booting from /dev/dsa
Like I said, I didn't use any of these tools to write to the /dev/sda, but but if I try to start /dev/dsa4 from the grub installed on /dev/sda, it begins booting but then stops, gives me a generic error and then restarts. This is the reason I think that the problem on /dev/nvme0n1 is grub.
I wish I could be giving some more specific error messages/codes, but I haven't seen any.
So I think that the problem can be broken down to 2:

Grub on /dev/nvme0n1 does not load either of the Windows partitions properly.
Something may or may not have happened to grub on /dev/sda, but obviously something's happening. One thing I'm worried about is using MS tools to correct this problem, since it tends to run roughshod over Linux installations.

I've tried Googling for these sorts of problems, but I'm short on specific keywords and a lot of the issues I find are from 10 years ago and probably not sufficient for my problem.

Do not post link to the Boot-Repair software, post link to the Summary report it creates. Did you install Windows? What brand/model system? UEFI or BIOS installs, report will tell us answers to some of that.

look at the Windows partition in /dev/sda4 Does it contain /boot and or /EFI or not?

It seems you have lost the Windows boot configuration data files (BCD) or it has changed.

To solve this problem, reboot by Windows installation media or HBCD-PE, You can reinstall or copy BCD files that support booting on either a UEFI-based or a BIOS-based computer from the C:\Windows folder to the root of C drive by the following command:
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL     #make sure that windows partition take the c letter

If the Windows partition takes another letter than c, you must assign the letter C for it before applying the above command. after that, reboot by Ubuntu and sudo update-grub. if this fixes the Windows boot of /dev/sda4, try the same solution with /dev/nvme0n1p2.

update:

I recommend HBCD_PE_x64.iso because when you boot by HBCD, you will find many tools like BootIce, EasyBCD, Windows disk management tool, cmd, and other tools in addition to the GUI as in normal Windows.

Create USB drive contains multi Ubuntu versions, HBCD-PE-64, and multi Windows installation from Ubuntu

to create a bootable USB for this ISO from Windows (I see in the comment you can use Windows):


open cmd, copy or write one by one, and enter:
diskpart
lis dis
sel dis x #replace x by the USB number
clean
create partition primary 
active
format fs=NTFS quick
assign letter=Z   #you can change the letter



Copy all the content in the ISO file to the root of the USB flash drive.

Now you can reboot by HBCD_PE, open the Windows disk management tool, and make sure that the Windows partition takes the C letter, if it takes another letter change it to C.



Open cmd and apply:
 bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL 

After Windows boot configuration data files are placed in the C partition, you can use BootIce to read and/or edit the BCD file











Reboot with Ubuntu to update-grub.

update 2
window's  grub menu entry 1:
menuentry "Windows" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos  
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos2' # edit this to appropriate with windows partition
        parttool ${root} hidden-
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
    }

if this menu entry doesn't work, use the second:
menuentry "Windows" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntldr
        set root='hd0,msdos2' # edit this to appropriate with windows partition
        ntldr /BOOTMGR
    }

may be you will try to set set root='hd0,msdos2' as set root='hd1,msdos2' make sure that windows partition take a bootable flag by disks utility.

I'll take that as a 'yes' for deleting the extra entry in BootICE... and doing so means I can now use the entry in /etc/grub.d/40_custom to start Win10 plain and simple. So how can I now make grub understand how it's supposed to start Windows without having that parasitical entry in the grub menu?

make sure that windows partition take a bootable flag by disks utility, enable os-prober to detect others systems from /etc/default/grub, and update-grub. at the end open grub.cfg and see how the windows entry presented.

I'm afraid the boot flag on the Windows partition (gparted) and the setup in /etc/default/grub are the way they are supposed to be. Just for kicks, though, I first backed up grub.cfg then followed https://askubuntu.com/a/1495226/412179 then did a diff between the old grub.cfg and the new and they were exactly the same. I tried the probed (vs the custom) grub entry anyway, and it still failed.

If the Windows entry by /etc/grub.d/40_custom still work, use it. I think you have to read this part from grub manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#DOS_002fWindows
