Can't boot 22.04 after booting 23.04
I have both installed on my harddrive, and I use 22.04 (jammy jellyfish) daily, but figured I'd boot into 23.04 (lunar lobster) one last time before deleting it since its end of life. Now when I boot it just boots automatically into 23.04 without a boot loader. I tried manually booting into GRUB, and the option to boot 22.04 is not there. When I go into the BIOS, its not there either, but when I boot into 23.04 and check Devices and Locations, my 22.04 partition is still there.
Also, after booting lunar, my grub menu looks different. It use to be on the top on the screen and now its on the middle of the screen and the resolution is different.
Why did booting into lunar seemingly change my grub, and how do I get back the option to boot into my 22.04 partition?

Booting into an OS would not change the grub settings, however you can perform commands whilst an OS is running that will do that, and you've not said what you actually did (and knowing what you did is usually the best clue on reversing the issue).  If 23.04 was first installed its grub may not have been configured for dual boot (thus grub doesn't show) and if you executed a command to make 23.04 take ownership of boot (even accidentally) that would explain what happened..  (grub not showing doesn't mean it can't be told to show; have you tried that?)

@guiverc afaict, the only thing I did was booting lunar. I booted it, used the browser, restart, and no option to boot jammy. The only thing I can think of is that it did try to update on startup but said it was up to date because its EOL. 23.04 was indeed installed first, so I guess thats the issue. What do you mean by grub not showing? Is the one in the middle of the screen not grub?

If Ubuntu installs and is the only OS you have installed, there is little reason to show grub so it runs silently or without anything appearing on the screen (ie. you don't see grub menu or see grub run)... that default isn't used in a dual booting environment, as the menu being visible & actionable is what is used to boot into your other (non-default OS).  If you boot 23.04 & perform sudo update-grub you should see the 22.04 being detected & thus added to the menu unless os-prober is not executed (a true/false flag controls this)

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375356/would-like-to-hide-grub-menu for clues on HIDDEN grub, but https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks OR https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475735/check-grub-disable-os-prober which will be more helpful if you're see the "Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions" type of warning with sudo update-grub

@guiverc Thanks for the info. I tried sudo update-grup and i do indeed get Warning: os-prober will not be executed... how do I get os-prober to execute? I'm reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475735/check-grub-disable-os-prober but I'm confused as to what I should be changing. Can I just run sudo update-grub GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER = FALSE? or do I have to change it in one of the grub files? because I cannot seem to find a file like the one shown in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375356/would-like-to-hide-grub-menu

We don't provide support for lunar or 23.04 as its EOL.  You edit the file (/etc/default/grub) using whatever text editor you're familiar with (it'll need elevated privileges of course due to location) then after saving you update grub using update-grub. The update-grub command will re-create the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file that is used at boot (what you're really wanting to change whilst on 23.04 - but there is a lot more to change if you edit that file).. allowing you to boot into 22.04 & then have it take ownership of boot (ie. grub-install) which is your real wanted fix.

so I added the line GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER = false to the etc/default/grub file, and ran sudo update-grub. Although grub is still giving me one ubuntu option, when I boot it, it gives me a second grub menu, allowing me to boot into 22.04, so thank you! You are correct though, I would very much like 22.04 to take ownership at boot. Given my current double grub situation, is it still as easy as using grub-install?

You just run grub-install from the OS you want to control the booting process; ie. boot 22.04 and run it from there and it'll take ownership of your machine's booting.. Do note grub-install requires a parameter, or what device to install the bootloader too... for my own machine I'd use sudo grub-install /dev/sda and it would install for me  (x86_64-efi platform it'll detect & report, so just use the appropriate device for your hardware... NOTE I install to drive, not partition (ie. sda and not sda9 where sda9 is a numbered partition on device sda)

@guiverc mine uses NVMe, so in dev I have /nvme0 and/nvme0n1. on /nvme0n1 theres my three partitions nvme0n1p1 (efi), nvme0n1p2 (23.04), nvme0n1p3 (22.04). Do I grub-install on /dev/nvme0 or /dev/nvme0n1? ty again.
